# Pandas dataframe.append giving Error: Plan shapes are not aligned

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, sklearn-pandas

I have two data frames with columns mentioned below. When I try to append the second one to the first one I am getting ValueError: Plan shapes are not aligned error.

**Df1 columns:**

```
Index([                    u'asin',        u'view_publish_data',

                u'data_viewer',      u'relationship_viewer',
             u'parent_task_id',            u'submission_id',
                     u'source',            u'creation_date',
                 u'created_by',              u'vendor_code',
                       u'week',                u'processor',
                 u'brand_name',           u'brand_name_new',
               u'bullet_point',               u'cost_price',
          u'country_of_origin',                 u'cpu_type',
               u'cpu_type_new',                u'item_name',
          u'item_type_keyword',               u'list_price',
     u'minimum_order_quantity',                    u'model',
           u'product_category', u'product_site_launch_date',
        u'product_subcategory',          u'product_tier_id',
     u'replenishment_category',      u'product_description',
                 u'style_name',                       u'vc',
                u'vendor_code',     u'warranty_description'],
  dtype='object')
```

**df2 columns:**

```
Index([                         u'asin',             u'view_publish_data',

                     u'data_viewer',           u'relationship_viewer',
                  u'parent_task_id',                 u'submission_id',
                          u'source',                 u'creation_date',
                      u'created_by',                   u'vendor_code',
                            u'week',                    u'brand_name',
                 u'bullet_features',                    u'color_name',
                             u'itk',                     u'item_name',
                      u'list_price',                     u'new_brand',
                u'product_catagory',          u'product_sub_catagory',
                 u'product_tier_id',        u'replenishment_category',
                       u'size_name',                    u'cost_price',
               u'item_type_keyword',                     u'our_price',
          u'is_shipped_from_vendor',      u'manufacturer_vendor_code',
             u'product_description',                  u'vendor_code'],
  dtype='object')
```

Comment: How do you append it?

Comment: They are two different dataframes with different columns, how would you append these?

Comment: I want to append it based on column names. If a column name is present in both the data frame, then the final data frame will have the column containing both. And if the column is not present in one of them, then that column in the final datframe should have NAN for the one which does not have that.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with [`align`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.align.html) what return tuple of aligned `DataFrame`s:

```
cols1 = pd.Index([ u'asin', u'view_publish_data',

                u'data_viewer',      u'relationship_viewer',
             u'parent_task_id',            u'submission_id',
                     u'source',            u'creation_date',
                 u'created_by',              u'vendor_code',
                       u'week',                u'processor',
                 u'brand_name',           u'brand_name_new',
               u'bullet_point',               u'cost_price',
          u'country_of_origin',                 u'cpu_type',
               u'cpu_type_new',                u'item_name',
          u'item_type_keyword',               u'list_price',
     u'minimum_order_quantity',                    u'model',
           u'product_category', u'product_site_launch_date',
        u'product_subcategory',          u'product_tier_id',
     u'replenishment_category',      u'product_description',
                 u'style_name',                       u'vc',
                u'vendor_code',     u'warranty_description'])

cols2 = pd.Index([ u'asin', u'view_publish_data',

                     u'data_viewer',           u'relationship_viewer',
                  u'parent_task_id',                 u'submission_id',
                          u'source',                 u'creation_date',
                      u'created_by',                   u'vendor_code',
                            u'week',                    u'brand_name',
                 u'bullet_features',                    u'color_name',
                             u'itk',                     u'item_name',
                      u'list_price',                     u'new_brand',
                u'product_catagory',          u'product_sub_catagory',
                 u'product_tier_id',        u'replenishment_category',
                       u'size_name',                    u'cost_price',
               u'item_type_keyword',                     u'our_price',
          u'is_shipped_from_vendor',      u'manufacturer_vendor_code',
             u'product_description',                  u'vendor_code'])
```

---

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([range(len(cols1))], columns=cols1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame([range(len(cols2))], columns=cols2)

df = pd.concat(list(df1.align(df2)), ignore_index=True)
print (df)

   asin  brand_name  brand_name_new  bullet_features  bullet_point  \
0     0          12            13.0              NaN          14.0   
1     0          11             NaN             12.0           NaN   

   color_name  cost_price  country_of_origin  cpu_type  cpu_type_new  ...   \
0         NaN          15               16.0      17.0          18.0  ...    
1        13.0          23                NaN       NaN           NaN  ...    

   style_name  submission_id    vc  vendor_code  vendor_code  vendor_code  \
0        30.0              5  31.0            9            9           32   
1         NaN              5   NaN            9           29            9   

   vendor_code  view_publish_data  warranty_description  week  
0           32                  1                  33.0    10  
1           29                  1                   NaN    10  

[2 rows x 46 columns]
```

Comment: If I have a list of dataframes, how can I do them using `align`? I am having a hard time figuring it out.

Comment: I posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53907083/pandas-data-frame-append-a-list-of-data-frames-that-have-inconsistent-columns), when you have time, feel free to check it out.